# d3: Refreshing the attr value on a subnode when data changes

Tags: d3.js

I'm rendering data with d3. I have a `nodes` list from which I construct a bunch of SVG groups using .enter(), like this (simplified):

```
nodes = [{name: "Fred"}, {name: "Barney"}];
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node");
var circ = node.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("r", 10)
node.append("svg:text")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

However, if I edit a listitem's `name`, the SVG text element does not update (because its `text` attr is only called on creation). How do I tell d3 to "recreate" the SVG group corresponding to a changed listitem? I'm doing this as part of a force layout, so I could set the `text` attr on every tick, but that's rather inelegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's needed is to feed the data back into the nodes again. So, when I've updated the `nodes` list, I do this:

```
vis.selectAll(".node text")
  .data(nodes)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

and that recalculates.